# Confused about a simple switch in PHP (5.5.38)

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have setup the following class which mimics one I am currently working on and trying to fix.

#### The goal

To return a fee (value) based on an initial value that is passed in.

#### The issues

I have two issues with the current code below:

1. When the first value that is passed in is **0** (zero) **12p** is returned which is incorrect - it should be caught by the first case and return **15p**.
2. I am yet to tackle it but I want to return the issuance fee for the last case that is satisfied (if the next ones are not defined). For the example below; the last restriction to be set is the `$lower_3` variable - which means that any value passed in that is greater than **31*** should return a fee of **10p**. I am however seeing that `null` is being returned as the checks just fall through to the last case.

#### The code

```
<?php

class IssuanceScheme
{
    private $lower_1 = 0;
    private $upper_1 = 20;
    private $issuanceFee_1 = '15p';

    private $lower_2 = 21;
    private $upper_2 = 30;
    private $issuanceFee_2 = '12p';

    private $lower_3 = 31;
    private $upper_3 = null; //50;
    private $issuanceFee_3 = '10p';

    private $lower_4 = null; //51;
    private $upper_4 = null; //75;
    private $issuanceFee_4 = null;

    private $lower_5 = null; //76;
    // no $upper_5
    private $issuanceFee_5 = null;

    public function calculateIssuanceFee($volume)
    {
        $issuanceFee = $this->issuanceFee_1;

        switch ($volume) {
            case ($volume >= $this->lower_1 && $volume <= $this->upper_1):
                $issuanceFee = $this->issuanceFee_1;
                break;
            case ($volume >= $this->lower_2 && $volume <= $this->upper_2):
                $issuanceFee = $this->issuanceFee_2;
                break;
            case ($volume >= $this->lower_3 && $volume <= $this->upper_3):
                $issuanceFee = $this->issuanceFee_3;
                break;
            case ($volume >= $this->lower_4 && $volume <= $this->upper_4):
                $issuanceFee = $this->issuanceFee_4;
                break;
            case ($volume >= $this->lower_5):
                $issuanceFee = $this->issuanceFee_5;
                break;
        }

        return $issuanceFee;
    }
}

$issuanceScheme = new IssuanceScheme;

// 15p
echo sprintf("Passed in: %s, Exp: %s, Got: %s", 0, '15p', $issuanceScheme->calculateIssuanceFee(0));
echo sprintf("Passed in: %s, Exp: %s, Got: %s", 5, '15p', $issuanceScheme->calculateIssuanceFee(5));
echo sprintf("Passed in: %s, Exp: %s, Got: %s", 10, '15p', $issuanceScheme->calculateIssuanceFee(10));
echo sprintf("Passed in: %s, Exp: %s, Got: %s", 15, '15p', $issuanceScheme->calculateIssuanceFee(15));
echo sprintf("Passed in: %s, Exp: %s, Got: %s", 20, '15p', $issuanceScheme->calculateIssuanceFee(20));

// 12p
echo sprintf("Passed in: %s, Exp: %s, Got: %s", 25, '12p', $issuanceScheme->calculateIssuanceFee(25));
echo sprintf("Passed in: %s, Exp: %s, Got: %s", 30, '12p', $issuanceScheme->calculateIssuanceFee(30));

// 10p
echo sprintf("Passed in: %s, Exp: %s, Got: %s", 50, '10p', $issuanceScheme->calculateIssuanceFee(50));
echo sprintf("Passed in: %s, Exp: %s, Got: %s", 60, '10p', $issuanceScheme->calculateIssuanceFee(60));
echo sprintf("Passed in: %s, Exp: %s, Got: %s", 75, '10p', $issuanceScheme->calculateIssuanceFee(75));
echo sprintf("Passed in: %s, Exp: %s, Got: %s", 100, '10p', $issuanceScheme->calculateIssuanceFee(100));
```

#### The result

```
Passed in: 0, Exp: 15p, Got: 12p // Error, expected is 15p
Passed in: 5, Exp: 15p, Got: 15p
Passed in: 10, Exp: 15p, Got: 15p
Passed in: 15, Exp: 15p, Got: 15p
Passed in: 20, Exp: 15p, Got: 15p
Passed in: 25, Exp: 12p, Got: 12p
Passed in: 30, Exp: 12p, Got: 12p
Passed in: 50, Exp: 10p, Got: // Not implemented (see goal 2, and not below)
Passed in: 60, Exp: 10p, Got:
Passed in: 75, Exp: 10p, Got:
Passed in: 100, Exp: 10p, Got:
```

The second goal hasn't been implemented but I want to return the last issuance fee that was satisfied. In this case **10p** should be returned as the values passed in are greater than **31**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand `switch` statement

```
switch($var) {
    case $val:
        //something
```

Means

> if `$var == $val` then do `//something`

So in your code it's:

```
switch ($volume) {
    case ($volume >= $this->lower_1 && $volume <= $this->upper_1):
        $issuanceFee = $this->issuanceFee_1;
        break;
```

which means

> if `$volume == ($volume >= $this->lower_1 && $volume <= $this->upper_1)` then do `$issuanceFee = $this->issuanceFee_1;`

Which is not true for `$volume=0`, because `($volume >= $this->lower_1 && $volume <= $this->upper_1)` is `true`, so you get condition `$volume == true` which is `0 == true`.

You need to reorganize your code probably into `if {} elseif {} else {}` statements.

For the second issue, you could change `$volume <= $this->upper_1` to `($this->upper_1===null || $volume <= $this->upper_1)`, and the same for other levels.

That will skip upper limit check if it's set to `null` (which means something like *unlimited*).

```
public function calculateIssuanceFee($volume)
{
    $issuanceFee = $this->issuanceFee_1;
    if ($volume >= $this->lower_1 && ($this->upper_1===null || $volume <= $this->upper_1)) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_1;
    }
    if ($volume >= $this->lower_2 && ($this->upper_2===null || $volume <= $this->upper_2)) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_2;
    }
    if ($volume >= $this->lower_3 && ($this->upper_3===null || $volume <= $this->upper_3)) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_3;
    }
    if ($volume >= $this->lower_4 && ($this->upper_4===null || $volume <= $this->upper_4)) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_4;
    }
    if ($volume >= $this->lower_5) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_5;
    }

}
```

Here's working example:
https://3v4l.org/uamib

```
Passed in: 0, Exp: 15p, Got: 15p 
Passed in: 5, Exp: 15p, Got: 15p 
Passed in: 10, Exp: 15p, Got: 15p 
Passed in: 15, Exp: 15p, Got: 15p 
Passed in: 20, Exp: 15p, Got: 15p 
Passed in: 25, Exp: 12p, Got: 12p 
Passed in: 30, Exp: 12p, Got: 12p 
Passed in: 50, Exp: 10p, Got: 10p 
Passed in: 60, Exp: 10p, Got: 10p 
Passed in: 75, Exp: 10p, Got: 10p 
Passed in: 100, Exp: 10p, Got: 10p
```

Comment: Thank you, I was expected the case to be evaluated, and not taken as-is. Using lots of if statements looks messy but might get the job done. How would I go about the second goal of returning the value for the last defined case?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It includes working example.

Comment: Thank you, the first `$issuanceFee = $this->issuanceFee_1;` isn't needed and apart from that it works great!

Answer (score 2):

Your use of the switch case is wrong. Whatever comes after `case` should be a value that matches whatever goes in `switch()`. An expression like `$volume > $lower` will be evaluated to a boolean, and this boolean will be compared with your `$volume` variable that goes in your `switch($volume)`.

I'd advise to just use `if` statements with early returns:

```
public function calculateIssuanceFee($volume)
{
    if ($volume >= $this->lower_1 && $volume <= $this->upper_1) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_1;
    }
    if ($volume >= $this->lower_2 && $volume <= $this->upper_2) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_2;
    }
    if ($volume >= $this->lower_3 && $volume <= $this->upper_3) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_3;
    }
    if ($volume >= $this->lower_4 && $volume <= $this->upper_4) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_4;
    }
    if ($volume >= $this->lower_5) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_5;
    }

    return $this->issuanceFee_1;
}
```

---

**Edit:** looking at your code again, what you probably really want is define a list of fees with their lower and upper bounds, and return a default fee if none match. Your code could be much more compact by specifying it like this:

```
class IssuanceScheme
{
    private $fees = [
        ['min' => 0, 'max' => 20, 'fee' => '15p'],   
        ['min' => 21, 'max' => 30, 'fee' => '12p'],   
    ];
    private $defaultFee = '10p';

    public function calculateIssuanceFee($volume)
    {
        foreach ($this->fees as $fee) {
            if ($volume >= $fee['min'] && $volume <= $fee['max']) {
                return $fee['fee'];
            }
        }
        return $this->defaultFee;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves the first issue. How would I return the last 'defined' case?

Comment: I'm going to disregard your number 4 and 5 cases, then I take it your 3rd case has no upper bound, which you encode as null. With your current code, I'd say just remove the `&& $volume <= $this->upper_3` and you're good. The thing is, `$volume <= null` will be evaluated as `$volume <= 0` which is not true.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am going to mark Jakub's answer as correct because it involves only changing the current implementation slightly. I will definitely take a look at the lookup-table approach though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on both your answers, I have switched the order and removed the upper bounds as I think this makes more sense. Please correct me if I am wrong, but it satisfies various values I am passing in.

```
public function calculateIssuanceFee($volume)
{
    if (isset($this->lower_5) && $volume >= $this->lower_5) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_5;
    }

    if (isset($this->lower_4) && $volume >= $this->lower_4) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_4;
    }

    if (isset($this->lower_3) && $volume >= $this->lower_3) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_3;
    }

    if (isset($this->lower_2) && $volume >= $this->lower_2) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_2;
    }

    if (isset($this->lower_1) && $volume >= $this->lower_1) {
        return $this->issuanceFee_1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, except you probably can drop the last `if` altogether and just return fee 1 by default. You could combine this logic with my fee list idea I just added to my answer.

Comment: Yes, that is true that I could drop the last check as it is superfluous. and it is the greater of all the values anyway so would be used as a default. Your approach of a lookup table as such sounds like a good idea. I shall take a look.